# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

getting error in java script all things works normal then why give this error,
i won't able to run the code which is written below this and this is google function which is important to use so how can i remove or is there any other way to solve the error

```
//Error is given on this line
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initGoogleMap);

//because of error this code not works
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            if(!marker.open){
                infoWindow.open(map,marker);
                marker.open = true;
            }
            else{
                infoWindow.close();
                marker.open = false;
            }
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.close();
                marker.open = false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Share your code so that we might be able to help you.

Comment: Where is your code??

Comment: here is my code i update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initGoogleMap);
```

Above code is for calling the function `initGoogleMap` at the time of window load. So there will be following reason of giving the error:

1. The function `initGoogleMap` you have not defined.
2. This is calling before the google map library load.

To resolve this follow the below statements:

- Remove or comment this line.
- Add the code `onload = initGoogleMap()` in the body tag. After that your body tag will be like this:

`<body onload = initGoogleMap()>`

Hope it will help you. If you have any query, asked me.

Comment: i add comment is for your understanding
and <body onload = initGoogleMap()> is not helping me out.
it shows like initGoogleMap() is not function but i already defined that function in my script

Comment: @ravipatel check where is you r script is at the bottom or at the top. If it is in bottom then add it at the top.

Comment: i'm really confused with this scripts ever. but really thanx it works with putting on top

Comment: how can i do that i am new to stackoverlow

Comment: i voted up but it shows error because i don't have at least 15 reputation

Comment: @ravipatel there is right sign below that. click on that